# i can't get the bluetooth devices in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i'm using xamarin android i want to get all the nearby bluetooth devices i tried this but it gives me an error saying: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
          BluetoothDeviceReceiver mReceiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
          RegisterReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
          mBluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery();

    class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.Action;
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();            
        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            // Get device
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
            // now you could do your job with newDevice
            ma.mArrayAdapter.Add(newDevice.Name + " -> " + newDevice.Address);
            ma.lsv1.Adapter = ma.mArrayAdapter;

        }

        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

the error at:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();            
ma.mArrayAdapter.Add(newDevice.Name + " -> " + newDevice.Address);
ma.lsv1.Adapter = ma.mArrayAdapter;
```

Comment: Is `MainActivity` is an `Activity` subclass? If so, you can not instance an Activity like that, you need to use `StartActivity`

Comment: how to use StartActivity can you help me please with some code?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/